# How to use Github with Xcode4's version control

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode4

The whole implementations seems very unstable. Sometimes I can push, sometimes it fails with 'no permission'.

Cloning through Xcode's Organizer behaves even stranger: The first time, it fails with no permission. When I click 'try again', it fails with some weird error like `can't store object BLABLA: No such file or directory`. If I click 'try again' another time, it succeeds.

Same behavior for Xcode's git and for a fresh homebrew-installed git (1.7.4.1).

Is this a problem on Github's side or is this a problem in Xcode?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with repositoryhosting.com so it's definitely an XCode 4 issue.

Comment: The same problem occurs using [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/). The first time it fails, but if you retry it, it succeeds.

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm using codespaces.com set up ssh keys, push always fails the first time, works from then on

Comment: This issue has completely solved in Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is solved in Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

An additional, although perhaps obvious step missing from: http://peterszwach.blogspot.com/2011/03/github-xcode-4.html is the need to:

"git remote add origin git@github.com:github_username/github_repo_name.git"

after you have navigated to the project directory in Terminal, otherwise git won't know where to make the push.

Comment: Nope, not the problem. My repository's remotes are set up correctly.